# Haskell library to manipulate a git repo

Tags: git, haskell

I am writing an application in Haskell that will have to perform basic operations on Git repositories (add, log, push, pull, fetch, diff etc.)

What are my options here (are there any apart from invoking shell commands from Haskell)? I could not find any good leads on Hackage.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are many good libraries for interacting with Git available on Hackage:

- [git-object](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/git-object) - parser and types for git objects
- [darcs-fastconvert](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/darcs-fastconvert) - tools for importing from git
- [ght](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ght) - trivial git interaction
- [libgit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/libgit) - simple git wrapper
- [hlibgit2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlibgit2) - full bindings to libgit2
- [gitit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitit) - wiki based on git
- [filestore](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filestore-0.4.0.4) - high level file-based interface to DVCS (git, darcs, etc).

You should be able to get started with these packages.

Comment: I like the contrast between this answer and the hal's one. :)

Comment: Don is [haskell]'s Jon Skeet

Answer (score 4):

Better than hlibgit2 is gitlib, which is a high-level set of type wrappers around the functionality of hlibgit2, designed for laziness, performance, and to suit a Haskell mindset.

Comment: "git fetch" is specifically mentioned -- I can't seem to find any support for it in Haskell's gitlib (wrapping libgit2). Is it supported?

Comment: Hi Peaker, fetching is supported by copying objects from one repository to another.  See the Push module.

Comment: Looks likes `gitlib` doc is broken: functions like `openOrCreateRepository`, `openRepository`, and `createRepository` as mentioned on [the doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib-3.1.2/docs/Git-Tutorial.html) are not found.