# Programatic interface to git commands

Tags: git, haskell

I saw this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6611686) to a question regarding packages to manipulate github repos, but after going though all the packages listed in the answer I can't see a way to say do a simple `git add`. I basically just want to emulate what I'm doing in git using a shell script at the moment but using Haskell so I don't need to directly call [`createProcess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:createProcess) to call command line git and do other fiddly things.

It seems the libraries are intended for a more lower level manipulation of git. Is this true or am I just missing something?

Comment: Have a look at the [*github*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/github-0.15.0) package, which didn't exist back when that question was asked.

Comment: I actually meant "git" not "github" (I've now edited the title) but yes that package maybe useful for me too thanks!

Comment: Another possibility is using [*turtle*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.3.2) to write your shell scripts in Haskell without the fiddliness. Here is [a piece of code](https://github.com/duplode/duplode.github.io/blob/5dad6f2c6d549d81f883654094a61907c3d420b3/src/Scripts.hs#L30) in which I used it for the exact same purpose that you describe.

Comment: I looked a month ago and was disappointed.  Sadly, this is off-topic for StackOverflow. The Haskell subreddit might be a more fitting place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but you can use `shell-conduit` to do it. It uses Template Haskell to give you a function named `git` to which you can pass appropriate parameters.

A sample working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-8.5
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package shell-conduit-4.6.1
 -}

{-#LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules#-}

import Data.Conduit.Shell

clone :: Segment ()
clone = do
  echo "Going to clone..."
  git "clone" ["--depth", "1", "https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-cookbook.git"]

main :: IO ()
main = run clone
```

Note that the above code will only work with `shell-conduit` version >= 4.6.0. If you are using a older version, you cannot pass list to the `git` function. Instead you had to do it like this:

```
git "clone" "--depth" "1" "https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-cookbook.git"
```

The new version accepts both way of doing things.

Full Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of shell-conduit.